# Is there a way to speed up the function call with concurrency?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

```
def process_file(csv_file_name):
    with open(csv_file_name, 'r') as f:
        csvreader = csv.DictReader(f)

        for i, row in enumerate(csvreader):
            results = keyword_extraction(row['text'])
            print(i, results['status'])

def keyword_extraction(text):
    results = []
    ...

    return results
```

Is there a way to call the function `keyword_extraction()` concurrently, either through threading or multiprocessing in Python?

Comment: Python only lets a single thread run at a time via the global interpreter lock - though calls to a C function can release that lock. If `keyword_extraction` is a cpu-bound python task, threads don't help. Multiprocessing can help but there is overhead. Unless `keyword_extraction` does a significant amount of work, it won't help either.

Comment: @tdelaney could you write an answer on how to use multiprocessing for concurrent in my example?

Comment: maybe you should use `pandas` for this. It uses code in C/C++ so it may works faster and you will no need to use concurrency. `pandas` has also some extension to run with `pyspark`, `ray` or other tools to run some code in separated threads, processes or even computers.

Comment: Hi, fura, could you write an answer of how to use pandas to do this for speedup for my example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of multiprocessing.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import csv

def process_file(csv_file_name):
     with open(csv_file_name, 'r') as f:
        # list of (index, row) pairs
        data = list(enumerate(csv.DictReader(f)))
     with mp.Pool() as pool:
        results = pool.map(keyword_extraction, data)
     for i, result in results:
        print(i, result)

def keyword_extraction(data):
     index, row = data
     results = []
     return index, results

# If this is a script, make sure code doesn't run on import
# to the subprocess in Windows
if __name__ == "__main__":
    process_file("my.csv")
```

Comment: No reason to read entire file into memory and pass the indices to the function (which just passes them right back) — so suggest using `results = pool.map(keyword_extraction, csv.DictReader(f))` and `for i, result in enumerate(results): print(i, result)`.